# Find synthetic members in class fields in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection, jacoco, synthetic

I am using the following method in scala to get hold of all the fields in a class:

```
  val fields = contract.getClass.getDeclaredFields.toList.map(value => {
  value.setAccessible(true)
  value.getName
})
```

`contract` has been defined as a class in my code.
Since I am using reflection, the problem is I get another element `$jacocoData` as one of the fields. I want to ignore this field. The 'hacky' way of doing it is to know the fact that it is always appended at the end of the list, so I can 'fix' it by changing my function signature to include `productArity` and only take the first `arity` number of elements like this:

```
  def getFields(contract: Contract, arity: Int): List[String] = {
     val fields = contract.getClass.getDeclaredFields.toList.map(value => {
     value.setAccessible(true)
     value.getName
  })
 //to ignore $jacocoData (Java code coverage) field
 val firstnFields = fields.take(arity)
 firstnFields
 }
```

According to the last point of [this FAQ](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/faq.html), I need to get rid off synthetic members of a class. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply assuming that `$jacocoData` is always the last element is dangerous, as `Class#getDeclaredFields()` [does not guarantee any order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29).

To check whether a field is synthetic use [`Field#isSynthetic()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#isSynthetic%28%29), so your code can be changed to:

```
val fields = contract.getClass.getDeclaredFields.
 toList.withFilter(!_.isSynthetic()).map(value => {
  value.setAccessible(true)
  value.getName
 })
```