# How to recognize an outer variable which is listed between members by reflection?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I have a function which constructs a map by reflection from an object literal (the purpose is to make porting some JavaScript code easier). The function works fine, but I have found a case in which the reflections lists variables from an enclosing scope between members:

```
def mapFromObject[T](m: Any): Map[String, T] = {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror

  def listMembers(m: Any) = {
    import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror

    val anyMirror = currentMirror.reflect(m)
    val items = for {
      symbol <- currentMirror.classSymbol(m.getClass).toType.members
      if symbol.isTerm && !symbol.isMethod && !symbol.isModule
    } yield {
      val field = anyMirror.reflectField(symbol.asTerm)
      symbol.name.decodedName.toString
    }
    items
  }


  def convertLiteral() = {
    val par_some = ""
    val literal = new {
      var item = new {}
      var item2 = new {
        var value = par_some
      }
    }
    println(listMembers(literal))
  }

  convertLiteral()
}
```

I expect to get result `item, item2`, but I get `par_some$1, item2, item` instead.

Why is `par_some$1` listed as a member of the class?

How can I check for such member, so that I can ignore it? I have tried various methods of `Symbol`, including `isSynthetic` and `isImplementationArtifact`, but nothing I have tried seems to be different from normal members.

Scastie repro: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/uiv4DBIERIKnZaiViZ0Aaw

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find synthetic members in class fields in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519347/find-synthetic-members-in-class-fields-in-scala)

Comment: @talex I don't know what is enough for the OP but that answer relates to Java reflection in Scala, not to Scala reflection used in this question.

Comment: @talex I am afraid it does not. I have specifically written in my question the `isSynthetic` does not help (meaning it is false) for the superfluous field.

Comment: @Suma You and talex are talking about different `isSynthetic`. You are talking about `scala.reflect.api.Symbols.SymbolApi.isSynthetic` . He is talking about `java.lang.reflect.Field.isSynthetic`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin You are correct. I have tried the other `isSynthetic` now and there is still no difference. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DWy801FsTvq2XKZwU8TVrw